# How to send/get PHP SESSION from page to page on IONIC 2?

Tags: php, angular, ionic2

I want to create a session in one of my php pages, so I can send it over to another php page. That way I'm trying to pass variables between them. I am using Ionic 2 and it seems my sessions are not being shared from page to page.

So far, I can create a session but I can't give it a use, since my other php pages are not recognizing them.

Here's my code:

PHP Page 1:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100");
header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

session_start();

$data3 = file_get_contents('php://input');
$objData2 = json_decode($data3);

$_SESSION["idCate"] = $objData2;

//Printing on console to check if my variable is being stored correctly
$olo = array("mensage"=>$_SESSION["idCate"]);
echo json_encode($olo); 

?>
```

PHP Page 2:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100");
header("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

session_start();

//$id = $_SESSION["idCate"];

$ola = array("mensage"=>$_SESSION["idCate"]);
echo json_encode($ola);

?>
```

Page 2 does not recognize my session. Why is that? How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello, did you able to solve this problem? I'm using the native http module, and cannot get the session cookies, all other cookies set with `setcookie` are set but the session cookie set with `session_start` won't set. It works with Angular http but we need to use native http, so it is not an option :(